# SLIC таблица в QEMU/KVM

Tags: linux-mint, виртуальная-машина, kvm

Не могу добавить SLIC таблицу в виртуальную машину KVM
Редактирую XML виртуальной машины через virsh edit, добавляю секцию примерно следующего содержания:
`<qemu:commandline>
  <qemu:arg value='-acpitable'/>
  <qemu:arg value='file=/path/to/SLIC.img'/>
</qemu:commandline>`

virsh пишет что домен изменился, но при запуске в командной строке не появляется опции -acpitable
При повторном редактировании, файл остается как был до редактирования
Используется virt-manager, как будто он затирает изменения

Comment: xml namespace `xmlns:qemu` в начале конфига указать не забыли? Очень незаметная деталь, хоть и описанная в доке https://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#qemucommand

Comment: Конфиг сформирован virt-manager'ом, там сейчас только <domain type='kvm'>, добавил строчку xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0', сохранения не изменились, смущает еще то что virsh edit, редактирует какой-то временный файл. Пишет что "XML-конфигурация домена Windows2008 изменена", но изменений нет

Comment: Поискав нашел что схема не сохраняется если не верная, проверяю с помощью **virt-xml-validate**, пишет ошибку **/usr/bin/virt-xml-validate: cannot determine schema type for /tmp/wintest.xml**. Добавлял xmlns:qemu, не помогает